# Change SCNPhysicsShape dynamically

Tags: ios, objective-c, scenekit, game-physics

I have created one golf table as mentioned [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/157211/designing-collider-for-a-table-with-a-hole-in-it). When the ball is over the hole, I changed the table's **SCNPhysics** shape to **concave** shape (mesh collider). When the ball lefts the hole, I set the table's **SCNPhysics** shape to **convex** shape.

After I set the SCNPhysics shape to convex shape, the ball start moving randomly.

I think modifying the SCNPhysics shape at run time is causing this problem. Is my assumption is correct? If yes, is there a solution to fix it?

I would appreciate any suggestions and thought on this topic.

Comment: When changing the shape are you doing anything with the physicsBody also?  Perhaps the node still has a movement vector that you should zero out.

Comment: Also, you can provide the table geometry to the SCNPhysicsBody for collider.  Is your issue that the ball won't drop into the hole?